# Android onShowCustomView view disappear of the app then visible again after video finish load

Tags: android, webview, html5-video

Android `onShowCustomView` view disappear of the app then visible again after video finish load.

I'm developing a mobie application, that load source from webservice with Youtube & Google plus my return json back to my webview, then I use html5 video, jwplayer, Youtube depends on my resources,

after show video I got an issue as my topic question:

```
    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {      

        Log.d(log_tag, "Full screen use!");
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;


        onum = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        //mTargetView.addView(view); // it's not ready yet
        mCustomView = view;
        mTargetView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // visible it first
        mTargetView.addView(view); // IF I TOOK THIS LINE OUT IT WONT DISAPPEAR BUT VIDEO CANT PLAY
        //mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        mTargetView.bringToFront();
        is_fullscreen = true;
    }
```

I notice mTargetView.addView(view); make app screen looks exit to the main desktop, 1-2 minutes after video could play then it showup again with my fullscreen video

Thanks in advance for any help